# how to add two button on toolbar in the left? I want to add two button on toolbar such as pic's 1 and 2

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-button

[image]

As shown in the above picture, this app has two Buttons on the ToolBar.
How did they do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` is a `ViewGroup`, which means you can just add views like add views into a `LinearLayout` or `FrameLayout` etc.

So you can just add your two buttons like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/Toolbar"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/first_button"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:src="@drawable/button_1_src" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/second_button"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="40dip"
        android:src="@drawable/button_2_src" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(actionBar.getDisplayOptions()
            | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(actionBar.getThemedContext());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.cancel_black);
    ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.LEFT
            | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    actionBar.setCustomView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first button doesn't have to be created...just call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpIndicator(Drawable upArrow);`
For the other button...just refer to the first post of @L.Swifter

But @L.Swifter...what you do in the second answer is adding two buttons...but you don't have to add two buttons...cause the first is default android menu button...which is drawn with `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`.